# MySQL case sensitivity table name on MacOS with case insensitive file system

Tags: mysql, macos, case-sensitive

I have researched a lot and what I understand to make database tables name sensitive, you have to set the variable lower_case_table_names=0.
Im on osX. I did this change in my.cnf.
After that, if I run

```
select * from users
```

I get results. While if I run:

```
select * from Users
```

I get error saying table doesn't exist.

However, for a particular database, the case sensitivity doesnt affect. I can use any case I will never receive errors. Why? I could have a look at the big sql-file used to import the database and try to find out if there are specific directives to ignore case sensitivity (?). 
Anyway, why you think the case sensitivity applies for all database but not the one Im interested in? One of those that does case sensitivity is InnoDB. While the one that doesnt care about this is MyIsam. Could it be the reason? Any work around in that case?

Comment: Tables and Columns are **Case Sensitive** in Linux!

Comment: Guys: I DO WANT the tables to be case sensitive. Im on osX. And cannot make this database to be case sensitive. It is case sensitive in Linux. I want it to be in osX too. Ok??

Comment: I found something very interesting. It seems that all the tables with the MyIsam engine doesnt care about sensitivity. If a table has InnoDB then it gives error if it has wrong case sensitivity.

Comment: This is similar question to the older question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768626/mysql-tablename-lowercase-after-osx-update

Comment: See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72284430/2016006. Other answers describe only the problem without a real solution.

Answer (score 6):

Tables and Columns are **Case Sensitive** in Linux! To make them case insensitive, follow this:

> Open terminal and edit `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
> ```
>
> Underneath the `[mysqld]` section, add:
>
> ```
> lower_case_table_names = 1
> ```
>
> Restart mysql
>
> ```
> sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
> ```
>
> Then check it here:
>
> ```
> mysqladmin -u root -p variables
> ```

Just altering the lower_case_table_names setting isn't enough.  It needs to be done before you import your database(s).

The [MySQL 5.7 documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) lists a procedure for moving between Windows and Linux/UNIX. A note about Mac OSX from that reference:

> One notable exception is OS X, which is Unix-based but uses a default
>   file system type (HFS+) that is not case sensitive. However, OS X also
>   supports UFS volumes, which are case sensitive just as on any Unix.

Review the manual page to ensure that your desired rules for enforcing case sensitivity are followed.  Take a look and verify that you did these steps in the correct order:

> To convert one or more entire databases, dump them before setting
>   lower_case_table_names, then drop the databases, and reload them after
>   setting lower_case_table_names:
>
> 1 - Use mysqldump to dump each database:
>
> mysqldump --databases db1 > db1.sql
>
> mysqldump --databases db2 >
>   db2.sql
>
> ... Do this for each database that must be recreated.
>
> 2 - Use DROP DATABASE to drop each database.
>
> 3 - Stop the server, set `lower_case_table_names` in the `[mysqld]` section of your `\etc\mysql\my.cnf` file, and restart the server.
>
> 4 - Reload the dump file for each database. Because lower_case_table_names
>   is set, each database and table name will be converted to lowercase as
>   it is recreated:
>
> mysql < db1.sql
>
> mysql < db2.sql

Concerning the MySQL System Variable [`lower_case_table_names`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names) Server Variable (or setting):

[image]

**Additional References:**

- [MySQL case sensitive table names on Linux](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16198/mysql-case-sensitive-table-names-on-linux)
- [How to make MySQL table name case insensitive in Ubuntu?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59407/how-to-make-mysql-table-name-case-insensitive-in-ubuntu)

Comment: This is a very thorough answer to the wrong question. The question is about MacOS.

Comment: @greggles I guess macOS is basically Unix so these should work right?

Comment: It is "basically UNIX" as its BSD, but it also has a different filesystem than most BSD systems which is case insensitive by default and which makes these instructions not accurate.

Answer (score 5):

MacOsx 10.13, docker 3.0.1.
Changing *lower_case_table_names* to *0* did not help me. Mysql gave error

```
[ERROR] The server option ‘lower_case_table_names’ is configured to use case sensitive table names but the data directory is on a case-insensitive file system which is an unsupported combination. Please consider either using a case sensitive file system for your data directory or switching to a case-insensitive table name mode.
```

Turning this setting `Use gRPC FUSE for file sharing` off in docker settings helped:
[image]

Comment: I have same issue with mysql. What confs you have in .cf file?

Comment: Fixed with this:

[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
skip-character-set-client-handshake
lower_case_table_names = 0

Comment: Man, you have saved me!!! Thanks so much! I found your answer after more than one hour searching on and its works perfectly to me. And the problem is related to the new Docker version

Answer (score 4):

The [case sensitivity of database and table names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) depends on the underlying OS and file system.

On Windows they **are not** case sensitive. On Linux they **are** case sensitive.

OSX is somewhere in the middle; the `HFS` file system supports both case-sensitive and case-insensitive file names (not on the same time though). It depends on how it was formatted.

Answer (score 2):

Only solution on MacOS goes neither over `lower_case_table_names` nor else settings of MySQL DBMS.

You need a case sensitive file system (volume). But fortunately it's easy to create it under MacOS:

- start the 'Disk Utility'
- Unter a main APFS-Container add a new APFS volume **with case sensitivity** (assume, we name it 'MysqlData', you can also define the size quota for this volume)
- move all the database binary data to this volume (in a directory in this volume i.e. `/Volumes/MysqlData/data`)
- make a symbolic link (assume our mysql data directory is `/usr/local/mysql/data`) to this volume:
  i.e.

  /usr/local/mysql/data ->  /Volumes/MysqlData/data

**DO A BACKUP OF `/usr/local/mysql/data` BEFORE!!!**

- start MySQL DBMS and load/import a DB (maybe you have to remove these DBs before) with uppercase tables
- voila: you will finally see these tables with uppercase

Comment: This should have been tagged as the accepted answer.  Super simple way to solve the issue!

Comment: Agree, it ended my 3 days of work on fixing this.

In my case, I needed to add lower_case_table_names to 0 on my.cnf to avoid errors.

Answer (score 1):

**By default, table aliases are case-sensitive on Unix, but not so on Windows or macOS. And you can't force this on OSX.**

The MySql documentation gives the following recommendation:

> To avoid problems caused by such differences, it is best to adopt a consistent convention, such as always creating and referring to databases and tables using lowercase names. This convention is recommended for maximum portability and ease of use.

> In MySQL, **databases correspond to directories within the data directory. Each table within a database corresponds to at least one file within the database directory** (and possibly more, depending on the storage engine). Triggers also correspond to files. Consequently, **the case sensitivity of the underlying operating system plays a part in the case sensitivity of database, table, and trigger names**. This means such names are not case-sensitive in Windows but are case-sensitive in most varieties of Unix. **One notable exception is macOS, which is Unix-based but uses a default file system type (HFS+) that is not case-sensitive.** However, macOS also supports UFS volumes, which are case-sensitive just as on any Unix. See Section 1.7.1, “MySQL Extensions to Standard SQL”. The lower_case_table_names system variable also affects how the server handles identifier case sensitivity, as described later in this section.

The recommended is use **lower_case_table_names=1** on all systems, but the disadvantage with this is that when you use SHOW TABLES or SHOW DATABASES, you don't see the names in the original case.

the variable **lower_case_table_names** is 0 by default, which means table names are stored as specified and comparisons are case-sensitive.

that is the possible values:

- 0: table names are stored as specified and comparisons are case-sensitive.
- 1: table names are stored in lowercase on disk and comparisons are not case-sensitive.
- 2: table names are stored as given but compared in lowercase. This option also applies to database names and table aliases.

> On Windows the default value is 1. On macOS, the default value is 2. On Linux, a value of 2 is not supported; the server forces the value to 0 instead.

### and here are your answer

> **You should not set lower_case_table_names to 0 if you are running MySQL on a system where the data directory resides on a case-insensitive file system (such as on Windows or macOS)**. It is an unsupported combination that could result in a hang condition when running an INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM tbl_name operation with the wrong tbl_name lettercase. With MyISAM, accessing table names using different lettercases could cause index corruption.

> An error message is printed and the server exits if you attempt to start the server with --lower_case_table_names=0 on a case-insensitive file system.

you can change this in my.cnf file, and you can find it using following command (if you are using unix-based system)

```
mysql --help | grep cnf
```

References:

[MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual Identifier Case Sensitivity](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

[MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual 5.1.7 Server System Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html)

Answer (score 0):

> However, for a particular database, the case sensitivity doesnt
>   affect. I can use any case I will never receive errors. Why?

This is because this database is simply created with option of case-insensitivity (by default). You need first to put case-sensitive option in the top of sql create script before the database creation, so the DBMS takes care.

Comment: What would this option with case-sensitivity be?

Comment: @user1963937 from your question `you have to set the variable lower_case_table_names=0. Im on osX`

Comment: Yes, but that directive is put in the conf file, in my.cnf. Can I just put "lower_case_table_name=0" in the sql that I run?

Comment: @user1963937 Is your database in your server that has `lower_case_table_name=0` in its my.cnf file? If no, then you cannot do that with a remote database, because its server maybe not configured to be case sensitive.

Comment: The database is a dumpfile I got. It comes from a server that runs linux. On my machine I run osX. And I changed lower_case_table_names to be 0 even on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Locate file at `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
2. Edit the file by adding the following lines:

   `[mysqld]`

   `lower_case_table_names=1`
3. `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

**You might need to re-create these tables to make it work**

Answer (score 0):

mysql manual states:

> If you plan to set the lower_case_table_names system variable to 1 on Unix, you must first convert your old database and table names to lowercase before stopping mysqld and restarting it with the new variable setting.

Answer (score 0):

In any new APFS based Mac you can do this which appears to be working. The following will create a new volume that which is case-sensitive (APFSX) that you can use for your volume data. Note: You should do this in a fresh directory.

```
mkdir <docker volume directory>
sudo diskutil apfs addVolume disk1 APFSX docker -mountpoint <docker volume directory>
sudo chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) <docker volume directory>
```

Ref: [Feature to opt-in into a case sensitive file-system (osxfs) on a volume mount](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/320#issuecomment-428656077)