# Mysql tablename lowercase after osx update

Tags: mysql, macos

I did a OSX update:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206770

After which it seems mysql saves all my new tables lowercase.

I use MAMP 3.5.2. The mysql settings is default for Mac OSX

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin variables | grep case
| lower_case_file_system                            | ON                                                                                                                     |
| lower_case_table_names                            | 2                                                                                                                      |
```

I noticed using:

```
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names=1
```

Saves my table camelCased, yet, using this setting it does not allow to search for camelCased table names since it will search for lowercase names.
Does anyone have a clue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OSX by default uses a journaled, case-insensitive file system.

For `lower_case_table_names = 1`

> Table names are stored in lowercase on disk and name comparisons are not case sensitive. MySQL converts all table names to lowercase on storage and lookup. This behavior also applies to database names and table aliases.

Based on the setting option for `lower_case_table_names = 2`

> Table and database names are stored on disk using the lettercase specified in the CREATE TABLE or CREATE DATABASE statement, but MySQL converts them to lowercase on lookup. Name comparisons are not case sensitive. This works only on file systems that are not case sensitive! InnoDB table names are stored in lowercase, as for lower_case_table_names=1.

Note that with this setting  Mysql will still save the innodb `.ibd` files a lower case even if you enable case sensitivity in Mysql (it does save the `.frm` table as you choose (camel case).

So, according to doc's it's acting as expected.

The take away:
You can't control the file system always (someone my port your schema to mysql running on linux, windows, etc...), so always assume its case insensitive and stick to all lower case for table names in mysql, an don't camel case.   I'd also recommend the same for database and column names.

Comment: Yes, I understand. We've always worked this way at my company. It's just that after the Mac OSX update, it does not work anymore.

Comment: @MaartenvanMiddelaar  inside mysql look at what the settings actually are `show global variables like "lower%"`, but I'm unsure why it was not work as noted above before you did the update.

Comment: Thanks Ray, it's another way to get the data. Little bit easier indeed.  Does not help finding an answer to my question though

Comment: Also, did you create your original tables via mysql on OSX or did you copy the data files directly from another machine?  If you did it on linux then copied the files over, they'd keep their case, but new ones created on OSX would not.

Comment: I've created most tables via mysql, reading a mysqldump. The last one via a create table statement

Comment: How did you upgrade?  Another final possible but unlikely options is you could have had the file system set to case sensitive  (an option in OSX, that breaks a lot of applications, but does work).  When you updated to El Captain, maybe it switched over to case insensitivity.

Comment: I once installed a version of OSX as case sensitive journaled and lots of fun ensued... Also is the mysql data on the main partition, maybe the partion or disk it's on isn't case insensitive

Comment: Partition is case insensitive. To be clear: It was not an update to el Capitan, it was an update of el capitan.

Comment: Got it, I'm at a complete loss on why an El Capitan update would change anything.   Any chance you have a time machine snapshot you can restore to another machine to try and test adding tables right before the update then right after the update so you're 100% the update was the only thing affecting your system?

Comment: Hmm. I do not have a snapshot so it's not possible to reproduce the previous state. yet, it seems that the update is not related to the error. I recently started to use the local db instead of a external db on a linux system and my first attempt to create a table happened only after the osx update. I guess it has never worked like I thought it would or should. :)

Comment: @MaartenvanMiddelaar Doh!